# Python - Plotting clusters from CSV

Tags: python, csv, plot

I'm a Python beginner.
I would like to plot some 2-dimensional clusters from CSV data.
CSV are formed by x, y and labels.
Example of CSV:

```
0.800717,0.84454,0
0.876446,0.626109,0
0.00504536,0.367249,1
0.0142114,0.794659,2
0.140504,0.240966,1
```

I'm trying with something like this but it's not working properly:

```
#!usr/bin/env

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

with open("kmeans.csv") as filein:
    reader = csv.reader(filein, skipinitialspace = True)
    xs, ys, label = zip(*reader)

plt.scatter(xs, ys)
plt.savefig("output.png")
```

Example of the current output:

[image: current output]
The expected result would be something like this (ignoring the centroids):

[image: expected output]

Comment: _it's not working properly_ - how exactly it is not working? Are there any error messages? Include them in your question.

Comment: I've updated the question as you suggested, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you use pandas, not the csv reader:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('kmeans.csv', header=None)
df.plot(kind='scatter', x=0, y=1, c=2, colormap='rainbow', colorbar=None,
        markeredgewidth=0.0) # No circle margin!
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, that was exactly what I needed and it is working properly. But I have a question, how is the color assigned for each label ("c" value)? I would like to add a legend but I don't know how to access the "c" value